# How am able to find out time zone used by mysql?

Tags: mysql

When I run mysql query to find out `created_at` time of interested table:

```
select created_at from snapshots;
```

It returns:

```
+---------------------+
| created_at          |
+---------------------+
| 2013-11-12 23:05:49 |
| 2013-11-15 01:02:08 |
| 2013-11-20 00:05:05 |
| 2013-11-20 00:25:38 |
| 2013-11-20 00:25:38 |
| 2013-11-20 00:41:11 |
| 2013-11-20 00:41:11 |
| 2013-11-26 22:43:47 |
| 2013-12-02 20:27:22 |
| 2013-12-02 20:27:22 |
| 2013-12-02 23:16:54 |
| 2013-12-02 23:16:54 |
| 2013-12-12 00:39:17 |
| 2013-12-12 00:40:21 |
| 2013-12-12 00:42:28 |
| 2013-12-12 00:46:33 |
| 2013-12-12 01:24:26 |
| 2013-12-12 01:26:34 |
+---------------------+
```

How am I able to parse this time (by another program) without information of time zone each associated with? Why doesn't MySQL store zone information or why it is not presented in the string value?

Comment: MySQL datetime does not store timezone information. The `timestamp` datatype does.

Comment: If you can try to save a new test entry, and you will see the current time. Then you can determine the time zone

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT @@time_zone;` will tell you what TZ the server is running in.

If it's a `DATETIME` field, it's stored with no timezone data. Essentially, plain text. Running `NOW()` will use the server's TZ.

If it's a `TIMESTAMP` field, it's stored as UTC under the hood but will be returned converted into the server's time zone.

Comment: when I run that I just get "systemtimezone" not a timezone value.

Comment: Then you need to run `date` on the server's command line to see what time zone it's using.